# Javascript radio button deselect others when selecting one radio button?

Tags: javascript, html

I have two radio buttons for selecting cars. There are only two options: either you can select a BMW car or you can select a Mercedes car.

Here's my html code for this:

```
<label>Please specify car:</label>&nbsp; &nbsp;
<label>BMW</label>
<input type="radio" name="is_BMW" id="is_BMW" onchange="valueChanged()" />
&nbsp;&nbsp;
<label>Mercedes</label>
<input type="radio" name="is_Mercedes" id="is_Mercedes" onchange="valueChanged()" />
```

The javascript function for this event is valueChanged() and it is pretty much straight-forward:

```
<script>
    function valueChanged(){
        if(document.getElementById("is_BMW").checked == true)
        {
            document.getElementById("is_Mercedes").checked = false;
        }
        else
        {
            document.getElementById("is_BMW").checked = false;
        }
    }
</script>
```

The problem I'm getting is this: whenever I click the BMW radio button, it get's fixed and I can't change to Mercedes.

If I click on the Mercedes radio button first, then I'm able to switch to BMW, but again, once I select BMW, I can't change to Mercedes anymore and it get's fixed.

Is there anything wrong with my Javascript? Because my Javascript knowledge tells me there's nothing wrong with my Javascript code. Is it something else? Should I use jQuery to resolve this?

**Edit-1**:
I'm sorry I forgot to mention one crucial point - I need to pass value onchange of radio button. I'm especially sorry to the one person who answered my question instantly, I should've mentioned this earlier, my bad.

Hence, my actual Javascript could should be something like this:

```
<script>
        function valueChanged(){
            if(document.getElementById("is_BMW").checked == true)
            {
                document.getElementById("is_Mercedes").checked = false;
                document.getElementById("is_BMW").value = 1;
                document.getElementById("is_Mercedes").value = 0;
            }
            else
            {
                document.getElementById("is_BMW").checked = false;
                document.getElementById("is_BMW").value = 0;
                document.getElementById("is_Mercedes").value = 1;
            }
</script>
```

Comment: No need to include javascript function. You can use Mritunjay code

Comment: Those labels need `for` attributes (or they need to wrap their inputs). They should also be on the *right* of the inputs, not left. http://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20-TECHS/H44.html

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I'm changing my answer according to your requirement.

In your **HTML** give same name to both radio buttons. This will take care of **select and deselect**.

```
<label>Please specify car:</label>&nbsp; &nbsp;
<label>BMW</label>
<input type="radio" name="car" id="is_BMW" />
&nbsp;&nbsp;
<label>Mercedes</label>
<input type="radio" name="car" id="is_Mercedes" />
```

And put the value changing logic in **js** like bellow

```
function valueChanged() {
    if (document.getElementById("is_BMW").checked == true) {
        document.getElementById("is_BMW").value = 1;
        document.getElementById("is_Mercedes").value = 0;
    } else {
        document.getElementById("is_BMW").value = 0;
        document.getElementById("is_Mercedes").value = 1;
    }
    console.log(document.getElementById("is_BMW").value);
    console.log(document.getElementById("is_Mercedes").value)
}
```

## Explanation:-

The name setting tells which group of radio buttons the field belongs to. When you select one button, all other buttons in the same group are unselected.

[**updated demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/mkdskd/8kt4eumr/1/)

Comment: What if I need to pass value on change? This is actually part of a PHP application, and depending on the car selection, some value is sent to database. If BMW is selected, then the value is 1 for `is_bmw` and 0 for `is_mercedes`, and it's sent to my PHP code by `$_POST` and then inserted into the database. (`is_bmw` and `is_mercedes` are 2 columns in my database table). Vice versa when Mercedes is selected.

Answer (score 7):

The radio button is unlike a check box because only one element can be selected at a time. But, in order for this to work, the radio buttons must be 'grouped' together.

This is done by specifying `input` elements with the same `name`.

In your example, this can be achieved by changing the following in your HTML:

```
<input type="radio" name="car_type" id="BMW" />
<input type="radio" name="car_type" id="Mercedes" />
```

No additional Javascript would be necessary to get the desired behavior.

Hope this helps offer some additional explanation!

**Edit:**
Not sure what you are trying to do, but you can extract the value by simply iterating over the radio elements in Javascript:

```
var r = document.getElementsByName('car_type');
for (var i = 0, i < r.length; i++) {
    if (r[i].checked) {
        // insert code to use the checked value
        alert(r[i].value);
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: No I don't need to extract value. It's just simply like a switch: if BMW is selected, then `is_bmw` = 1, and `is_mercedes` = 0. Vice versa if Mercedes is selected. `is_bmw` and `is_mercedes` are two columns in my database table. In my PHP code, using `$_POST` I can get these two 1 and 0 values, and then run an `INSERT` query to pass those values to database. Savvy?

Comment: Okay I see. Then I think your Javascript code in your original post works perfectly fine. I would just remove the lines `document.getElementById("is_XXXX").checked = false;` from inside the code blocks, since that was already taken care of by the radio element group. Then, it should be fine.